# yum error - centos 7.1 x86_64

Tags: dns, centos, yum

I'm facing an issue with the yum command on a dedicated server (hosted by OVH):

```
[root@mail-server ~]# yum clean all
[root@mail-server ~]# yum update
Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror


 One of the configured repositories failed (Inconnu),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

After investigation, i found that the error bellow (the url return not ok from the dedicated server) :

KO From dedicated server :

```
[root@mail-server ~]# curl "http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7.1.1503&arch=x86_64&repo=os"
Invalid release
[root@mail-server ~]#
```

OK From home (ADSL)

```
MacBook-Air-de-John:~ jjohn$ curl "http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7.1.1503&arch=x86_64&repo=os"
http://mirror.ate.info/ftp.centos.org/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
http://ftp.rezopole.net/centos/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/linux/centos/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
http://mirror0.babylon.network/centos/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
http://centos.crazyfrogs.org/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
http://centos.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.centos.org/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CentOS/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
ftp://ftp.free.fr/mirrors/ftp.centos.org/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/Centos/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
http://ftp.ciril.fr/pub/linux/centos/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/
MacBook-Air-de-John:~ jjohn$
```

I got the same issue after a fresh install and on a friend's dedicated server (hosted by OVH too).

I don't know if the error is coming from OVH network (DNS, ...) or mirrorlist.centos.org server.

Answer (score 27):

I solved the problem by typing

```
# dhclient
```

Comment: Solved my issue - not sure why you got the downvotes.

Comment: Please explain why this helps. Tossing out a fix is ok but explaining why it works and should be used educates the user so they understand what they're doing.

Comment: solved my issue on CentOS I installed from ISO everything in virtual box.. I also did a `sudo yum update` afterward

Answer (score 1):

Your DNS doesn't seem to resolve the centos mirror list

Use

> # dhclient

or Add "nameserver 8.8.8.8" in "/etc/resolv.conf" file

> # vi /etc/resolv.conf [press i] now you are in insert mode
>
> nameserver 8.8.8.8  [press: Esc][press :wq]
>
> #

hope it work's..!

Answer (score 0):

first you have to go to the /etc/yum.repos.d directory and edit the CentOS-Base.repo using vi editor. look for following lines;

mirrorlist=

## baseurl=

remove the # sign in the #baseurl if you have difficulties in accessing the baseurl/mirrorlist web address using yum then save and exit the vi editor.

goodluck and enjoy the yum package-management utility in linux.

Best Regards-KB